# Number of pairs of coprime positive integers $(a, b)$ such that $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{14b}{a}$ is an integer?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, fractions, coprime

> How many pairs of positive integers $(a, b)$ are there such that $a$ and $b$ have no common factor greater than $1$ and $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{14b}{a}$ is an integer?

The problem I'm facing in this question is that is there any algebraic or short-cut method to find the pairs. Else I've done it by Hit and Trial but that consumes a lot of time.

Comment: Another way to say this is: $$\frac{a^2+14b^2}{ab} \text{ is an integer}$$ I'm not sure if this helps, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for coprime integers $a$ and $b$ for which
$$\frac{a}{b}+14\frac{b}{a}=\frac{a^2+14b^2}{ab},$$
is an integer. Then $b$ divides $a^2$, and so $b=1$ because $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Now the above reduces to
$$\frac{a^2+14}{a},$$
which is an integer if and only if $a$ divides $14$, i.e. $a\in\{1,2,7,14\}$.

Comment: Why $b$ divides $a^2$?

Comment: Because $b$ divides $a^2+14b^2$, because the shown fraction is an integer.

Comment: Why not $a$ divides $b^2$?

Comment: @Qwerty:  you also have $a$ divides $14b^2$, but factors can come from $14$ as well.

Comment: @Qwerty You have $ab$ divides $a^2+14b^2$ from the fraction. However, obviously, $b$ divides $ab$. Combine these two to get $b$ divides $a^2+14b^2$. Then, since $b$ divides $14b^2$, we get $b$ divides $(a^2+14b^2)-14b^2=a^2$

Comment: @qwerty It's easier using the Rational Root Test - see my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Let $\, x = a/b.\,$ $\,x+14/x = n\,$ so $\, x^2\!-nx+14 = 0\,$ so $\ b\mid1,\,a\mid 14\,$ via [Rational Root Test.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

Comment: I don't know what's Rational Root Test .. Can you explain it to me !!

Comment: @Amritanshu I added a link.